# I was at my parents. Vs. I was at my parents'./I was at Chris. vs. I was at Chris's

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

I am wondering which sentences from the following sentences is correct:

> I was at my parents.

or

> I was at my parents'.

> I was at Chris.

or

> I was at Chris's.

Comment: The possessive is correct in both cases, because the implied meaning is _at my parents' house/home/flat_.

Comment: It's acceptable to use *Chris'* as the possessive as the last letter is s.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first sentence ("I was at my parents.") does not make sense.  The apostrophe in this scenario shows **possessive**.

"I was at my parents'." is the same as saying "I was at my parents' place".  Seeing this makes it much clearer why the apostrophe is needed.  Your parents own the place.

Saying "I was at my parents." without an apostrophe means that I am at "my parents", as if they are a location (similar to "I am at the store").

Everything here is the same for "Chris".

Here is a link that might be helpful:
https://www.apostrophechecker.com/rules-for-possessive-apostrophes/